# prepare for Segue is not being called

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have read a dozen posts on SO. Some of them suggest using Override, but I get a compile error as that function definition is now `open`.

```
self.user = user
performSegueWithIdentifier("selectPayment", sender: nil)

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! SelectPaymentViewController
    vc.user = user
}
```

that bottom function is never called. Why is this? Targeting iOS `9.2`

Comment: which function is not called

Comment: Try changing the sender from nil to `self` also make sure `selectPayment` is the correct name  you assigned to the segue in the storyboard.

Comment: the bottom function, the only `func` definition in my post. documented in UIViewController.h as `@available(iOS 5.0, *)
    open func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`

Comment: @apineda that doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you have written this code, in view controller or any other class as you stated... not allowing to override, mean your code is not inside view controller.... Please share complete class here

Comment: @Monster I did check that. It's within the class definition of `class MyViewController: UIViewController`

Comment: @it measn you call in more than once in your current VC, ensure once

Answer (score 0):

This was just an issue with the calling syntax.

the correct implementation is

`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {`

Comment: what are you using swift3 or below

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. I need to upgrade the project's Swift syntax. Thank you!

Comment: but your question is written in swift 3 not below, that the reason I added my answer in swift3

Comment: I did get a prompt from Xcode earlier about that, but ignored to proceed with features.